# How to return an error from a HTTPS Cloud Function?

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, google-cloud-functions

Calling a Cloud Function from an iOS app looks like this:

```
var functions = Functions.functions()
functions.httpsCallable(name).call(data){ (result, error) in
    // Code here
}
```

How can I send an error from my Cloud Function, so it will get picked up in the above code? For example:

Cloud Function:

```
exports.joinGame = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
     return Error("The game is full")
})
```

SwiftUI:

```
var functions = Functions.functions()
functions.httpsCallable("joinGame").call(data){ (result, error) in
    print(error) // "The game is full"
}
```

Comment: The Cloud Function is just returning an HTTP response. If you catch an error on the function's side, you should return an appropiate HTTP response code: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6 . Then, you handle that HTTP response code from your local code as any regular response from an HTTP request.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to do in SwiftUI.

Comment: Calling the cloud function will return: (`HTTPSCallableResult?`, `Error?`) in SwiftUI - I want to return an error message from my cloud function that will appear under the 2nd parameter of the response (`Error`). @Asperi

Comment: The semantics of an HTTP call mean you probably shouldn't return an error, rather you should return a `response` that contains success/fail details; the http request worked, but the application was unable to process the request because the games was full, so the application response should indicate that, not the http response

Comment: @Paulw11 That makes sense. I will return `{ error: "error message" }` or `{ success: "success message" }` depending on the scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a better approach.  You could also return `{ "success": true/false, "message":null/"Game full" }` or whatever

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure where do you want to return error... but here is some variants of possible handling:

```
@State private var error: Error?

var body: some View {
   VStack {
     Text("Wait for Error")
       .onAppear {
         functions.httpsCallable("joinGame").call(data){ (result, error) in
            print(error) // "The game is full"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.error = error
            }
         }
     }
     if nil != error {
        Text("Got error!")   // << do anything with error here
     }
   }
   .onChange(of: error) { newError in
                            // << or here 
   }
}
```